# Azure Function using Hybrid Connections to connect on-premises API

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am currently trying to use an Azure function to connect to some on-premiseS API endpoints. Currently for reasons I cannot go into I am attempting to use the IP address for the endpoints in the Hybrid Connection. For some odd reason I cannot connect to that IP address. I have checked our Firewall Logs, LB, and the HCM box on-premises event logs. None of these show any kind of attempt at connection. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please include any output or screenshots of results.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of couple of ways to achieve this :

- Create a VPN connection and [Integrate a Function App with an Azure Virtual Networ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet)k
  you can consider this path : On-premise ----> s2s ( Site to Site) VPN ----> VNet ----> function in a subnet of VNet.

You may follow : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal

- Check [Azure Service Bus relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/)

For reference :
https://www.stefanroth.net/2019/01/13/azure-functions-azure-functions-using-hybrid-connections/

https://yourazurecoach.com/2017/09/26/azure-function-proxies-part-2-easily-enable-hybrid-integration/

However, if if you need assistance for application specific issue, you may consider reaching out to Microsoft Support.